# Persisting navigation graph positioning in Android Studio navigation editor

Tags: android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-editor

Is there a way to persist the position of nodes in the navigation graph when using Android Studio? Maybe even check into version control. I would imagine those positions are written to some file in `.idea` but couldn't find a reference to any such file.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?